# Mysql Procedure Syntax change to Firebird Procedure Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, firebird

I don't know what's different about the stored procedure of firebird syntax.

MySql Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CAL_SHIFTDTL]
(
  @PSHIFTDTEFROM DATETIME,
  @PSHIFTDTETO DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   DECLARE @GEN_EXCEPTION_FROM DATETIME,
           @GEN_EXCEPTION_TO DATETIME

   SELECT @GEN_EXCEPTION_FROM = @PSHIFTDTEFROM,
          @GEN_EXCEPTION_TO = @PSHIFTDTETO
```

How can I change this one syntax for Firebird stored procedure?

```
SELECT @GEN_EXCEPTION_FROM = @PSHIFTDTEFROM,
       @GEN_EXCEPTION_TO = @PSHIFTDTETO
```

Comment: first, here is no full procedure text, only beginning. Second - as usual with imperative languages (C++, Basic, Pascal, etc), you retell the procedure into a normal human English language, then retell it back into Firebird's PSQL language. Here is the manual and examples on PSQL language: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql.html

Comment: In particular, simple variable assignment like `a = 2+2;` does not need quazi-select operator. https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-coding-assign

Comment: You mention MySQL and have tagged it, but the syntax shown looks more like Microsoft SQL Server's T-SQL. What are you really using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in Firebird PSQL syntax would be simple assignment, so `GEN_EXCEPTION_FROM = PSHIFTDTEFROM;` See also [Assignment Statements](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-coding-assign) in the Firebird Language Reference. The full equivalent of the fragment shown in your question would be:

```
RECREATE PROCEDURE SP_CAL_SHIFTDTL
(
    PSHIFTDTEFROM TIMESTAMP,
    PSHIFTDTETO TIMESTAMP
)
AS
DECLARE GEN_EXCEPTION_FROM TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE GEN_EXCEPTION_TO TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    GEN_EXCEPTION_FROM = PSHIFTDTEFROM;
    GEN_EXCEPTION_TO = PSHIFTDTETO;
```